# Signalr hubconnection.Start not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, signalr-hub

I m using SignalR but I have a problem. There is table called `Discussion.when` data insert, trigger call API service

**the codes in API service**

```
public async void Triger(int ID)
{
    try
    {
       var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:57278");
        IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("DiscussionHub");
        await hubConnection.Start(new LongPollingTransport());
        stockTickerHubProxy.Invoke("RefreshData", ID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

**But it is throwing the following error**

> StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:   {
>
> X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcw7ZtZXJcRG9jdW1lbnRzXGFwY3Vyc1xhcGN1cnNcYXBjdXJzXERpc2N1c3Npb25IdWJcc2lnbmFsclxuZWdvdGlhdGU=?=
>   Cache-Control: private     Date: Tue, 27 Feb 2018 17:40:20 GMT
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET   Content-Length: 3284   Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> }

**and this is Hub class**

```
public class DiscussionHub : Hub
{
    public static object _lock = new object();
    public static DiscussionsModel dataList = new DiscussionsModel();

    public void RefreshData(int ID)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            SubDiscussionModel sdm = new SubDiscussionModel();
            DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();
            if (!dataList.subDiscussions.Any())
            {
                var discussion = (from q in db.Discussions
                                  select new DiscussionsModel
                                  {
                                      id = q.id,
                                      user = q.User,
                                      discussionText = q.DiscussionText,
                                      createdDate = q.CreatedDate,
                                      viewCount = q.ViewCount,
                                      shortTitle = q.ShortTitle,
                                      isWantEmail = q.IsWantEmail,
                                      status = q.Status,
                                  }).Where(a => a.id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

                DiscussionsModel data = discussion;
                dataList = data;
            }
            else
            {

                SubDiscussion data = db.SubDiscussions.SingleOrDefault(ga => ga.id == ID);
                sdm.id = data.id;
                sdm.status = data.Status;
                sdm.text = data.Text;
                sdm.user = data.User;
                sdm.createdDate = data.CreatedDate;
                sdm.discussionId = data.DiscussionId;

                dataList.subDiscussions.Add(sdm);
            }

            string viewName = @"~/Views/discussions/SubDiscussionListPartial.cshtml";
            var discussionScreen = Helper.GetRazorViewAsString(dataList, viewName);
            Clients.All.refreshData(discussionScreen);

        }
    }
}
```